# Old IIS Site Cached after Publish VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, iis

I am used to having IIS automatically reset a website any time any of it's "key" files change (such as the DLL's in the bin folder or changes to the web.config).  As a result, any time I "publish" the website using VS2012 - the target IIS site (even if it's on another server) always restarts itself so that additional testing can be done.

A project I'm working on this week for some reason is not doing this.  I can completely delete and republish the site - and yet IIS keeps serving up the "old" content until I recycle the associated AppPool.  It reliably updates when I recycle the AppPool - and reliably does NOT update until I do so (seemingly regardless of which files are on the disk).

It's as though it's caching my entire ASP.NET 3.5 website.  I have been working with IIS for almost 20 years, and I've never seen it behave anything like this.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement allows you to programmatically recycle the AppDomain (similar to recycling the whole AppPool, but involving only the current application so anything else is untouched)

```
HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();
```

I usually `#if(DEBUG)` it in my projects so it doesn't make its way out of the dev environment.